# Nginx equivalent configuration in angular2 cli

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, webpack, angular-cli

I am new to angular2. I have been using Nginx for my angular1. How to configure these settings in angular2-cli

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/cloudface/;
proxy_cookie_path /cloudface/  /;
```

Comment: You can still use nginx with angular 2. I dont know much about Nginx config, but if you describe what you're looking for maybe i can help you setup the angular cli server.

Comment: sure . @thanks. I need to set my angular CLI server for production..

Comment: is it recommended to use angular cli server for production @AhmedMusallam

Comment: You should never use angular cli server for production. It's only meant as a dev server. If you are already using Nginx, keep using it for angular 2 as well for production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular-Cli is not for production. It is a development server. So these things are likely not necessary to set up in angular-cli. for backend proxy can be achieved by [Setup Backend proxy](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md)

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a full guide available on the [official documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/deployment.html) that explain everything you need to know to properly deploy your application on a production server. There is even a part dedicated to `Nginx` configuration.

I would also advise you to take profit of [Angular-CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) to properly handling everything related to `bundling`, `optimizing` and `AOT compilation`.

Comment: Thank You so much. I will try that out